# Calculating dimensions for a shipment/stack of items

Tags: php, math, dimensions

I am looking into writing a PHP function that uses a convenient method/formula to calculate the dimensions of i.e. a parcel/pallet loaded with items.

Here is an example of an array with items. Note: Some items are flagged to be sent as separate parcels. Some items may not be tilted.

```
$items = array(
  1 => array(
    'quantity' => 1,
    'weight' = 1,
    'dimensions' => array(80, 50, 50), // Length, Width, Height
    'separate' => true, // If the item should be sent as a separate package 
    'tiltable' => false, // False if the item has a 'this side up' sticker
  ),
  2 => array(
    'quantity' => 3,
    'weight' = 1,
    'dimensions' => array(21, 15, 10),
    'separate' => false,
    'tiltable' => true,
  ),
  3 => array(
    'quantity' => 2,
    'weight' = 1,
    'dimensions' => array(18, 19, 20),
    'separate' => false,
    'tiltable' => true,
  ),
  // ... and so on ...
);
```

Does anyone have the slightest bit of knowledge or experience from doing this? I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

The function I have in mind is something like this:
* (Syntax errors may occur) *

```
  function build_packages($items, $max_weight=0, $max_length=0, $max_width=0, $max_height=0) {

    $packages = array();

  // Step through each item
    foreach ($items as $item) {

    // Twist and turn item. Longest side first ([0]=length, [1]=width, [2]=height)
      if (!empty($item['tiltable'])) {
        rsort($item['dimensions'], SORT_NUMERIC);
      } else {
        if ($item['dimensions'][0] < $item['dimensions'][1]) {
          $item['dimensions'] = array($item['dimensions'][1], $item['dimensions'][0], $item['dimensions'][2]);
        }
      }

    // Validate item
      if (!empty($max_weight) && $item['weight'] > $max_weight) return false;
      if (!empty($max_length) && $item[0] > $max_length) return false;
      if (!empty($max_width) && $item[1] > $max_width) return false;
      if (!empty($max_height) && $item[2] > $max_height) return false;

    // Step through quantities
      for ($i=0; $i<$item['quantity']; $i++) {

      // Step through packages
        $package_found = false;
        foreach (array_keys($packages) as $key) {

        // Skip to next package on certain conditions
          if ($packages[$key]['separate']) continue;
          // ...

          // Do some logic
          // ...

        // Modify package
          $package_found = true;
          $packages[$key]['num_items']++;
          $packages[$key]['weight'] += $item['weight'];
          $packages[$key]['dimensions'] = array(0, 0, 0); // <--- Replace with new dimensions

        // Twist and turn package. Longest side first ([0]=length, [1]=width, [2]=height)
          if (!empty($item['tiltable'])) {
            rsort($packages[$key]['dimensions'], SORT_NUMERIC);
          } else {
            if ($packages[$key]['dimensions'][0] < $packages[$key]['dimensions'][1]) {
              $packages[$key]['dimensions'] = array($packages[$key]['dimensions'][1], $packages[$key]['dimensions'][0], $packages[$key]['dimensions'][2]);
            }
          }

          break;
        }

        if ($package_found) continue;

      // Add to a new package
        $packages[] = array(
          'num_items' => 1,
          'weight' => $item['weight'],
          'dimensions' => $item['dimensions'],
          'separate' => $item['separate'],
          'tiltable' => $item['tiltable'],
        );
      }
    }

    return $packages;
  }
```

Care to help out with some code?

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is a solution to the [Bin Packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) problem.  The solution is [NP Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard) so you may want to find a "good enough" solution, rather than the optimal solution.  A google search turned up this: [One Dimensional Bin Packing](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6522-PHP-Implementation-of-one-dimensional-bin-packing.html) class.  I did not look at the code, so I am not sure how good it is, but I suggest it as a place to at least start your investigation.  If it turns out to be good enough for one dimensional problems, perhaps you can create a solution creating multiple 1 dimensional layouts and keep track of each row's max height, therefor knowing whether you have exceeded the total package height.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I found this Package https://github.com/dvdoug/BoxPacker and this service https://3dbinpacking.com/ so far that does this for you.